# Align left in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I create a tcolorbox environment to display on my Maths lessons the name of the activity in a framed box.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{docstyle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\renewcommand{\doctitle}{Statistiques}
\newcommand{\auteur}{Nom Professeur}
\newcommand{\studyprogram}{Terminales}
\newcommand{\suni}{Mathématiques}


\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}
\newcommand{\summary}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{#1\par}}

% Contenu du Docstyle
%\ProvidesPackage{docstyle}

\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{{Tableau}}}
\addto{\captionsfrench}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Compétences à acquérir}}

% Layout packages
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\LaTeX \quad C'est super!}
\fancyhead[R]{Académie de Poitiers}
\fancyfoot[C]{Rubrique \LaTeX}
\fancyfoot[R]{\today}
}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[some]{background}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.83} % Couleurs à partir de http://latexcolor.com
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, allcolors=black}

% References
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% Sciences and Math packages
\usepackage{semtrans}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{capt-of}


\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

% Horizontal line and separator
%\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
%\newcommand{\hseparator}{\hspace{0.3em}-\hspace{0.3em}}


% !!!!!!! Header des pages !!!!!
\lhead{\suni\hseparator\studyprogram}
\rhead{\doctitle}




\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\parindent=0mm
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[number within=section,list inside=toc]{activite}[1]{enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm,yshifttext=-2mm},
colback=aquamarine!8, 
colframe=aquamarine!2!black, 
colbacktitle=aquamarine!8,
title={#1},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\bfseries,
coltext=black,
coltitle=black,
boxed title style={size=small,colframe=black}
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}.}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection})} 


\begin{document}
        \tableofcontents 
        \addtocontents{toc}{
        \protect\thispagestyle{empty}} 
        \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \newpage
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Activité}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip15pt \ruleline{\bfseries Activités} \vspace{1mm}} 


\begin{activite}
{Activité 1}{Nom de l'activité}
\end{activite}
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{activite}
{Activité 2}{Nom de l'activité}
\end{activite}
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{activite}
{Activité 3}{Nom de l'activité}
\end{activite}
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{activite}
{Activité 4}{Nom de l'activité}
\end{activite}
\lipsum[1-1]


\end{document}
```

The environment "Activite" is created with

```
\newtcolorbox[number within=section,list inside=toc]{activite}[1]{enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm,yshifttext=-2mm},
colback=aquamarine!8, 
colframe=aquamarine!2!black, 
colbacktitle=aquamarine!8,
title={#1},
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\bfseries,
coltext=black,
coltitle=black,
boxed title style={size=small,colframe=black}
}
```

The part of the code `[number within=section,list inside=toc]` is used to add the information in the ToC.
But the problem is, in the ToC, the content is NOT aligned on the left (as in the picture).
Does someone have an idea to help me?
Thanks!
Antoine
[image]

Comment: Please make sure your example is self contained. What is `docstyle`?

Comment: Where is the `activite` environment defined? I see no `\newenvironment{activite}...`. In the text a `\begin{environment}` is ended by an `\end{environment}`.